# Brother printer does not work after installation

Tags: drivers, printing, 16.04, scanner, brother

I have problems with the installation of a Brother Printer Model DCP-375CW. I tried to install it on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
I downloaded the drivers for linux from the brother website,
dcp375cwcupswrapper-1.1.3-1.i386.deb
dcp375cwlpr-1.1.3-1.i386.deb

I installed both via GDebi Program. 
The printer is still not working. It is detected and I can add it but it would not print a test page. 
The printer is connected via USB.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance.

PS: I read somewhere that you should change settings at 
http://localhost:631/printers
but for some weird reason I cannot access this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My FIX...

My Brother DCP-J140W wifi printer+scanner stopped working after a 16.04 install. The Brother Installer complained about some unknown directories, bad file descriptors, etc. I eventually reinstalled CUPS then re-ran the installer. Now printer + scanner working.
As follows:

```
apt-get purge cups   
apt-get install cups
sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1 DCP-J140W
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works perfect for Ubuntu 19.04 and Brother DCP-1622WE

Comment: This works perfectly for DCP-426W, in Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 15):

I had problems while installing a Brother HL-L2365DW on Ubuntu 16.04 as a network printer. I've used the official Brother `linux-brprinter-installer` from their website but the printer was not working. Fortunately the fix was simple.

1. Go to *Printers → Your printer properties*
2. Hit *Change* on *Device URI*
3. Wait 10 seconds until all active printers show up in the list
4. Choose your printer (*LPD network printer*, **not** *IPP network printer via DNS-SD*)
5. Hit *Apply*
6. In *Printer properties* change the *Device URI* host name to the IP address of your printer so it looks something like `lpd://192.168.1.45/BINARY_P1`
7. Hit *OK* and the printer should work

If you want to find the IP address of your printer try doing `ping PRINTERHOSTHERE`. The printer will not respond to a ping but you will see the IP that your system was trying to ping and that is the IP of your printer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Very nice first answer.

Comment: This worked 100% for me with Ubuntu 16.04 and a Brother MFC-L8690CDW printer.
Both printer and scanner are working fine now.

On an Ubuntu 18.04 system, the official installer by Brother worked right away.

Comment: DUDE you are a life saver, this was the exact fix I needed. Switching from IPP to LDP and changing to IP address is the key indeed.

Comment: I'm surprise no mention of this at all on Brother's official guide.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Brother HL-2270DW. After I installed 16.04 The printer would be configured, but would not be available (what ever that means).  Then I discovered that the Device URI in System Settings was not the same as what it was with 14.04.  I manually changed it to be the same as what it was with 14.04 and the printer works fine now.  I can't explain why, but maybe this might give you some ideas.

Comment: What was your Device URI?